# How to get a composer/npm project onto production webserver?

Tags: web, npm, composer-php

I've searched the web but I've not really found an answer which I am happy with...

If I'm ready with a project which uses npm or composer to upload it onto a webserver how excactly do I "export" it to the webserver. Because you normally you dont upload the complete node_modules directory to the webspace because you don't have to waste the space with development files e.g. demos or something. So you can upload just the needed files onto the webserver but what is with the links and with a big project this would also mean a lot of work grabbing out just the files you need.

So what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When deploying JS parts, you usually compile them from a lot of modules to a small number of files (maybe a single one). You only need to deploy the compiled parts (that's why you can skip `node_modules`). A good example might be the source code of jQuery which you can find at https://github.com/jquery/jquery/tree/master/src. It consists of many files, while the ["compiled" version](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/tree/3.5.1/dist) only consists of a single, more dense file. Having readable files in development helps to oversee changes - having a single dense file in production speeds up the deliverance using HTTP.

In contrast, PHP is not a compiled language, but one that needs all source files (both your self-written code and the libraries in `vendor`) on the server to be interpreted. On running your application, all neccessary files are read. Keeping preloading or OpCache besides, this means: really **reading** these exact files, not some compiled versions. That's why you can not skip deploying all these files.

If you search for parts to skip: if you don't plan to run your application in development mode, you can call `composer install --no-dev` in your deployment scripts. This removes dependencies that are only needed for the development, like Symfony's profiling and web toolbar, or CI tools like PhpUnit or PHPCS

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! I just have one question. What do you mean with compile?I thought Javascript also has functions like require to import projects or to import javascript into a html file. E.G. I have a html site and I import Javascript with <script src="node_modules/example/example.js"></script> But in the example folder I most of the time have also files like demo or something which I don't need.